# DXF Export won't work

Tags: qgis, export, mac, dxf

I'm new to using GIS data.

Using QGIS I'm trying to export a DXF file from a .shp file from the NYC OpenData site.

I can open the file, pan, zoom, select the area I want to export, etc, but when I go to Project>DXF Export the export fails every time.

There are many different settings within the DXF Export dialog box, but I'm not sure what they mean or what should be selected.

The map data I'm trying to export are very simple NYC building footprints.

I'm on a Mac running OS10.10.

Ideally I want to export a DXF file that I can import into SketchUp.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  You said that "the export fails every time" but would you be able to [edit] your question to include the text of any error message that you see, please?  Since using SketchUp in a later part of your workflow is not directly related to this particular place that you are stuck I am removing that tag.

Comment: Apart from `Project -> DXF Export`, you can also rightclick on the layer -> `Save As ...`, and choose DXF format. Please add to your question what error message you get.